# How does taking modulo 1 make sense?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, hash

I need some help understanding the problem statement in CLRS 11.3-4 pg 269.  It says:

> Consider a hash table of size $m = 1000$ and a corresponding hash function 
>    $ h(k) =\left \lfloor m(kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor $
>   for $A = (\sqrt5 - 1)/2$. Compute the locations to which the keys
>   61, 62, 63, 64, and 65 are mapped.

Is $\mod 1$ a misprint in my copy? Also $A$ is a real number.  Is modulus defined for non-integer numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to for clarifying mod 1 concept , for constant $\mathcal{A}$ I got the proper explanation in **CLRS** itself it says :
Although this method works with any value of the constant $\mathcal{A}$, it works better
with some values than with others. The optimal choice depends on the characteristics of the data being hashed. Knuth suggests that
$$
\mathcal{A} \approx (\sqrt(5) - 1)/div 2 = 0.6180339887 ...
$$
is likely to work reasonably well.
As an example, suppose we have $ \mathcal{k} = 123456, \mathcal{p} = 14, \mathcal{m} = 2^{14} = 16384,$  and $ \mathcal{w} = 32.$ Adapting Knuth’s suggestion, we choose $\mathcal{A}$ to be the fraction of the form $$\mathcal{s}/2^{32}$$ that is closest to $$(\sqrt(5) - 1)/ 2,$$ so that $$ \mathcal{A} = 2654435769/2^{32}.$$ 
Then $$\mathcal{k}  . \mathcal{s}  = 327706022297664 =(76300 . 2^{32} )+  17612864,$$ and so $\mathcal{r_{1}}  = 76300$ and $\mathcal{r_{0}} =  17612864.$ The 14 most significant bits of $ \mathcal{r_{0}} $ yield the value $\mathcal{h}(k) =  67$.

Answer (score 8):

That's not a misprint.  $kA \bmod 1$ makes sense.  For instance, $37.239 \bmod 1 = 0.239$.

Comment: ok thanks this was the first time I came across mod for non integer.So What is the final mapping.

Comment: @p.j Note that the common definition for modulo does not need that any of the numbers is integer: $a \mod b = c \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}.\ a - bk = c$. (Typically, one requires $c < b$ to get a well-defined operation, but in mathematics modulo is used as a relation.)

Comment: What I think he used this hash function because after solving decimal part is changing even for small change in number , I am still not sure  but it seems it will give less number of collision.